# Reading csv file from s3 using pyarrow

Tags: pandas, aws-lambda, pyarrow

I want read csv file located in s3 bucket using pyarrow and convert it to parquet to another bucket.
I am facing problem in reading csv file from s3.I tried reading below code but failed.Does pyarrow support reading csv from s3 ?

```
from pyarrow import csv

s3_input_csv_path='s3://bucket1/0001.csv'
table=csv.read_csv(s3_input_csv_path)
```

This is throwing error
"errorMessage": "Failed to open local file 's3://bucket1/0001.csv', error: No such file or directory",

I know we can read csv file using boto3 and then can use pandas to convert it into data frame and finally convert to parquet using pyarrow. But in this approach pandas is also required to be added to the package that makes package size go beyond 250 mb limit for lambda when taken along with pyarrow.

Comment: seems more like FileNotFound error, it depends on whether Pyarrow has permissions to read on your VM?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a file handle to `pyarrow.csv.read_csv` instead of an S3 file path.

Note that future editions of `pyarrow` will have built-in S3 support but I am not sure of the timeline (and any answer I provide here will grow quickly out of date with the nature of StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same question - I'm using polars though.

I think this [help page](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/formats.html) is a good overview.

For some consistency with parquet files I use `s3fs`.
While parquet supports giving the [filesystem](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem) as parameter directly, `csv` does not out of the box.

```py
from s3fs import S3FileSystem

# create s3 access
s3 = S3FileSystem()

def get_csv_data(fname: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    from pyarrow import csv
    with s3.open(fname, 'rb') as source: # open as binary!
        # pandas:
        return csv.read_csv(source).to_pandas()
        # polars:
        # return pl.from_arrow(csv.read_csv(source))

def get_parquet_data(fname: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
   import pyarrow.parquet as pq
   ds = pq.ParquetDataset(fname, filesystem=s3, filters=...).read()
   # pandas:
   return ds.to_pandas()
   # polars:
   # return pl.from_arrow(ds)
    

# the s3:// prefix needs to be removed
input_csv_path='bucket1/0001.csv'
table=get_csv_data(input_csv_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a project ([AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)) that helps with the integration between Pandas/PyArrow and their services.

Example of CSV read:

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_csv(path="s3://...")
```

[Reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible as of now. But here is a workaround, we can load data to pandas and cast it to pyarrow table

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
df = pd.read_csv("s3://your_csv_file.csv", nrows=10). #reading 10 lines
pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

from s3fs import S3FileSystem

s3 = S3FileSystem() # or s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=ACCESS_KEY_ID, secret=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

s3_input_csv_path = f"s3://bucket1/0001.csv"

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(s3_input_csv_path, filesystem=s3)

table = dataset.read_pandas().to_pandas()

print(table)

s3_output_csv_path = f"s3://bucket2/0001.csv"

#Wring table to another bucket

pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, 
                    root_path=s3_output_csv_path,
                    filesystem=s3)
```

Comment: Thanks for response...I am getting this error.[ERROR] OSError: Passed non-file path: s3://bucket1/0001.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler

Comment: Do you have that file in s3 bucket ?

Comment: ArrowInvalid: Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.